Swift 6 Migration: Handling Weak Delegates in a Sendable Context
I’m trying to wrap my head around Swift 6’s concurrency model while migrating some code that uses a weak delegate, and I want to minimize changes. Suppose I have a delegate defined like this:
protocol ServiceDelegate: AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}

And a service interface:
protocol ServiceProvidable {
    var delegate: ServiceDelegate? { get set }
    func load()
}


The implementation looks something like this:
final class ServiceProvider: NSObject, ServiceProvidable, URLSessionDelegate {
    weak var delegate: ServiceDelegate?

    func load() {
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}

With Swift 6 enabled, I get the following error:
Stored property 'delegate' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'ServiceProvider' is mutable

Possible Solutions
As I see it, I have a few options, but each comes with its own trade-offs:

Isolate ServiceProvidable to an actor (e.g., @MainActor): This approach would involve bigger refactoring for other code

Create a thread-safe wrapper around the delegate: I could implement a wrapper that ensures thread-safe access to the delegate
and then mark the wrapper as @unchecked Sendable. Here’s what this
could look like:


protocol ServiceDelegate: AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}

protocol SafeServiceDelegateProvidable: Sendable {
    var delegate: ServiceDelegate? { get set }
}

protocol ServiceProvidable {
    var safeDelegate: SafeServiceDelegateProvidable { get }
    func load()
}

final class ServiceProvider: NSObject, ServiceProvidable, URLSessionDelegate {
    let safeDelegate: SafeServiceDelegateProvidable = SafeServiceDelegateProvider()

    func load() {
        safeDelegate.delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}

final class SafeServiceDelegateProvider: SafeServiceDelegateProvidable, @unchecked Sendable {
    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")
    private weak var _delegate: ServiceDelegate?

    var delegate: ServiceDelegate? {
        get {
            queue.sync { _delegate }
        }
        set {
            queue.sync { _delegate = newValue }
        }
    }
}

However, there’s a complication: safeDelegate needs to be updated (e.g. service.safeDelegate.delegate = self) after initialization, and since it can’t be a let constant, changing it to a var results in error:  Stored property 'safeDelegate' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'ServiceProvider' is mutable
Question
What would be the easiest or most effective solution to this problem? Are there better ways to handle weak delegates in Swift 6, given the concurrency changes?

Why can't safeDelegate be a let? Why does it need to be set a second time? It is safeDelegate.delegate that will be set later, not safeDelegate itself, right?

Apologies, perhaps I used the wrong wording. safeDelegate needs to be updated (not set) after initialization, for example, service.safeDelegate.delegate = self. And that results in an error: Cannot assign to property: 'safeDelegate' is a 'let' constant

Ah I see. Adding a : AnyObject constraint to SafeServiceDelegateProvidable should work then. Or just change the type of safeDelegate to the concrete class SafeServiceDelegateProvider directly. Do you really need it to be a protocol?

sash, I understand the appeal of option 2 (as it silences the compiler warning), but are making promises that might not be entirely true. Namely, you are synchronizing access to delegate, but the delegate, itself, might not be Sendable. If you are going to do this, I might be inclined to define the protocol to ensure that ServiceDelegate is actually Sendable, i.e., protocol ServiceDelegate: AnyObject, Sendable {…}. Now, that places additional burdens on your refactoring, but just be wary of @unchecked Sendable for an accessor to a type that might not, itself, be Sendable.

Also, a minor point, but I might suggest making the synchronization queue a constant, e.g., private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: …). Not a big deal, but it might more accurately reflect your intent.

@Sweeper Thanks, that fixes the issue. No, it doesn’t have to be a protocol; I can remove it. Does it provide any benefits?

@Bob Thanks. Yes, I agree it is not Sendable, but how does that impact things? I assumed that as long as I can access the delegate in a thread-safe way, I shouldn’t run into any problems. Could you please explain more?

@sash "as long as I can access the delegate in a thread-safe way, I shouldn’t run into any problems" is a tautology :-) What Rob meant was that you are not meeting the requirements of Sendable. It is still dangerous to send SafeServiceDelegateProvider across threads. An example situation would be, some other thread may hold a reference to the same object as delegate. That thread can do things to delegate without accessing it through SafeServiceDelegateProvider. If delegate has some sort of mutable state and is not an actor, you get a race.

safeDelegate.delegate can be set if the compiler can determine that safeDelegate has reference semantics. You can constraint the protocol to AnyObject:
protocol SafeServiceDelegateProvidable: AnyObject, Sendable { .. }

Or, you can change the type of safeDelegate to the concrete class SafeServiceDelegateProvider instead. I don't see how SafeServiceDelegateProvidable is useful here.
protocol ServiceProvidable {
    var safeDelegate: SafeServiceDelegateProvider { get }
    func load()
}

final class ServiceProvider: NSObject, ServiceProvidable, URLSessionDelegate {
    let safeDelegate = SafeServiceDelegateProvider()

    func load() {
        safeDelegate.delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}

As Rob says in the comments, to actually make SafeServiceDelegateProvider fulfil the requirements of Sendable, ServiceDelegate needs to be Sendable too.
protocol ServiceDelegate: AnyObject, Sendable {
    func doSomething()
}

Otherwise, SafeServiceDelegateProvider is still not safe to send across threads. Consider:
class NotSendable: ServiceDelegate {
    var someProperty = 0
    func doSomething() {
        someProperty += 1
    }
}

@MainActor
class Foo {
    let notSendable = NotSendable()

    func doSomething() {
        let provider = SafeServiceDelegateProvider()
        provider.delegate = notSendable
        Task.detached {
            // here I sent 'provider' to some other thread
            // doSomething is going to increment someProperty
            // this is going to race with the line 'notSendable.someProperty += 1' just below
            provider.delegate?.doSomething()
        }
        notSendable.someProperty += 1
    }
}

